Confusion matrix not displaying values in the bottom quadrants
I am working on a logistic regression. I get a confusion matrix, that doesn't show values consistently at the 2 bottom quadrants. I'm using 7.0.8 in a Jupyter Notebook, all packages I have imported I verified are up to date. I'm using sklearn.metrics.
Here is where I get and process the data set:
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y_logistic_test, logistic_predictions), annot=True, fmt='d',  cmap='Blues')
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('Actual')
plt.title('Confusion Matrix - Logistic Regression')
plt.show()

enter image description here
I had tried to downgrade the version as well as trying using a different dataset and it seems it is the same issue whenever i uses logistic regression - confusion matrix.
